# I'm getting a "missing value" error when running this for/if code in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get rid of the rows in which indeXLE$XLE == 0 by running this code:

```r
for (i in 1:6975) {
  if (indeXLE$XLE[i] == 0) indeXLE <- indeXLE %>% slice(-i)
}
```

But I'm getting the "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error. Any thoughts?

Comment: you don't need to do this one by one in `for` loop. Try `indeXLE <- subset(indeXLE, XLE != 0)`

Comment: Check for `NA`. See, for example, that `NA == 0` is `NA`, which is not welcome in an `if` block, `if (NA == 0) 1 else 2`.

Comment: Similarly, make sure that your hard-coded `1:6975` does not exceed the number of rows, since `mtcars$disp[999]` is `NA` (see my previous comment). It is generally far safer to make a `for` loop programmatically, e.g., `for (i in seq_len(nrow(indeXLE)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [filter](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/filter) function from the dplyr package.

```r
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

indeXLE <- filter(indeXLE, !is.na(XLE) & XLE != 0)
```

Comment: I suggest adding `!is.na(XLE)`, since the error suggests the presence of `NA`. \*shrug\*

Comment: @r2evans Done. Good catch.

Comment: Also, "rdocumentation.org" is woefully unmaintained, and your link references 0.7.8 which was updated Feb 2019 (20 months ago). As an alternative, https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/filter.html (good for most R packages) or https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html (specific to tidyverse).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.